# Laravel 5: Show image in View with Intervention resize() method

Tags: php, laravel-5, intervention

I can show resized image with this code inside route,

```
Route::get('/create', function(){
    $img = Image::make('assets/tes.jpg')->resize(200, 200);
    return $img->response('jpg');
}
```

But how I can return resized image from Controler to View ?

Here is my Controller

```
publc function show($id){
$image = /*What code here ? resize assets/tes.jpg to 200x200*/
return view('some', compact('image'));
}
```

Here is my View `some.blade.php`

```
<img src="$image">
```

or should I resize on upload and save it, instead of resize on the fly ?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: You could always use Intervention’s own [image cache](http://image.intervention.io/use/cache) if you’re wanting to resize thumbnails on the fly. But the best approach is to resize on upload, and then stream an appropriately-sized thumbnail in your web pages.

Answer (score 2):

> should I re-size on upload and save it, instead of re-size on the fly

Yes, If you are worried about the split seconds (but noticeable time) it takes to re-size and render images on the fly then you are better off with re-sizing on upload and saving various sizes.

Coming to how to display re-sized image in the view:

You can simply specify your route URL:

I am using `public_path("/assets/$img")` because I assume your images are located in `public\assets`

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/assets/{img}',function($img){
    return \Image::make(public_path("/assets/$img"))->resize(200, 200)->response('jpg');
});
```

You can even play with the sizes:

```
Route::get('/assets/{img}/{h}/{w}',function($img, $h=200, $w=200){
        return \Image::make(public_path("/assets/$img"))->resize($h, $w)->response('jpg');
 });
```

**Later in the View:**

```
<img src="{!! url('assets', ['tes.jpg']) !}}">
```